# React multi select hierarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-select

I have two select tag

- Select A
- Select B

I want the values from the **Select B** are populated depending on the values selected in **Select A**.

I have reproduced a little example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-ud8rg?fontsize=14) where the user has to pick a league in **Select A** and in **Select B** he has to pick up the team of the league selected in **Select A**.

I have looked around to find similar examples in codesandbox and jsfiddle.

I need some examples or some tips on how to figure it out. I have found any.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: when u select a value from dropdown A based on that update ur `this.state.value`
create a event listner and change ur state

Comment: i need to see an example doing the same or edit my codesandbox

Comment: i post an answer it might help u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-45zgu). Basically you should've restructure your data a bit for easier access (everything under one object). Then you need to track which league is selected and which team is selected. On every league change, you need to refresh your team list (basically filter required teams) like this:

```
const getTeams = league =>
  league && data[league]
    ? data[league].map(name => (
        <option key={name} value={name}>
          {name}
        </option>
      ))
    : [];
```

Of course you'll need to change your data filtering structure if the data is going to come from backend, but I hope you get the idea. For initial state I'm using first league thats defined in `data` object, and first team that corresponds to that league - of course you can change implementation of that how it fits your needs.

Comment: The only thing not very clear to me is this : //league && league !== ""//

Comment: @Koala7 If you call getTeams() or getTeams(""), then just return empty array (0 teams). Maybe even better check would be league && data[league] to ensure that teams for requested league exist.

Answer (score 1):

Take onChange on ur `select` and declare a function there. Inside that function catch ur selected value. and accoroding to that change ur state

```
export default class Chart extends Component {
  state = {
    list1: [...liga],
    list2: [...leagues]
    value: []
  };

 changeBDrop(event){
     var aVal = event.target.value;
     if (aVal === 'A') {
         this.setState({ value: // ur value })
     }else {
         this.setState({ value: // ur value })
    }

 };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="main">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-5 title-container" />
                <div className="col-xs-7 form-container">
                  Pick the League:
                  <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.changeBDrop} >{listLeagues}</select>
                  <br />
                  League Teams to be selected
                  <select value={this.state.value} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is just a concept example which will help u to understand what you have to do